# Problems with initializing player object in Deezer api

Tags: deezer

I was trying to launch an example http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript/example-invisible 
The example works fine under firefox however I get the following error in google chrome 30.0.1599.101 on mac

```
http://developers.deezer.com/examples/player_invisible.php dz.js:67
playercontrol is not defined dz.js:67
ReferenceError: playercontrol is not defined
    at DZ.inapploaded (http://cdn-files.deezer.com/js/min/dz.js:8:5)
    at DZ.communication.receive (http://cdn-files.deezer.com/js/min/dz.js:109:1)
```

Comment: Hi, I keep having this issue again and again. Clearing my cookies helps, but not for long. Have you found out how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try deleting your cookies?

Please let me know if you get the problem again.

Comment: Will users also have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug from Deezer. The SDK has issues while running in iframes, it's been fixed now.